# What is the risk of not using Magento's "getSubmitUrl" function?

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, security

This produces a URL that includes some encryption. If I want to create a custom "Add to Cart" button and use my own link:

`"/checkout/cart/add?qty=1&product=2"` that does not have this encryption, what is the risk? If it's important, I'm only dealing with simple products.

---

To be clear, the `getSubmitUrl($_product)` that I'm referring looks like:

```
/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS9mcmFasdfasdfasdfasdfadsfadsfh0bWw,/product/18/
```

Answer (score 4):

The only risk is that it won't work if you upgrade to `1.8`.
That encoded parameter is actually `Mage::helper('core')->urlEncode($this->getCurrentUrl());`. That means is the current url base64-ed. (and a little modified to be url safe).
The `urlEncode` method looks like this.

```
public function urlEncode($url)
{
    return strtr(base64_encode($url), '+/=', '-_,');
}
```

That parameter is used only if you have `Redirect to cart` set to `No` for after adding a product to cart.
It won't work for `1.8` because there is a new security "thing" that requires the form key when adding something to the cart.
To make it upgrade safe use this instead:
If you have the product as an object do this:

```
$url = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, array('qty'=>2));
```

if you have only the product id use this:

```
$product = new Varien_Object(array('entity_id'=>$productId));
$url = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product, array('qty'=>2));
```

Comment: Holy cow. Thank you so much. You confirmed I have nothing to be concerned with now, but saved me from probly an entire day of banging my head when I do upgrade!